# Manage un-replied Gmail conversations

Tags: gmail

On average, I send about three emails a day to people I may have never emailed before, or have but don't see regularly. In both cases I forget that I've emailed them, so if they don't reply then the conversation is 'lost' forever.

My ideal solution: I know Gmail stores the message, but I want some kind of added notification system, or dashboard, or report that says "Hey, in the last 5 days you sent out 20 emails that still haven't been replied to yet." And I can see which ones still haven't been replied to and then re-send a message.

Comment: Is there any particular business reason that you need to do this, this sounds fishy and related to spam.

Comment: The business reason is to initiate and maintain relationships. Not really going to argue the spam thing - Obviously I'm going to say it's not spam but you'd just have to take my word for it. I've got a nice little pile of points building up at stackoverflow.com if that makes me any more credible.

Comment: @wag2639. Dude, this is for productivity of course.. real spammers don't need a human to do these kind of things.

Answer (score 8):

Apply a label to the message you send (e.g., "Waiting for Reply"). Then you can check that folder every few days to see which messages have been responded to and remove the label as appropriate.

I use a filter to look for a specific string in the body of the message to automate adding the label.

Comment: This can also be accomplished by BCCing `<your email here>+WaitingForReply@gmail.com` so you don't have to find the email again after you've clicked "Send".

Comment: True enough, but then you need to remember to add the address in the bcc field.

Comment: Gmail will start suggesting that you add your email address after you do it a few times

Answer (score 6):

You can try [Boomerang](http://www.boomeranggmail.com/) for Gmail. It has also add-ons for Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Can you expand on how that will solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

http://followupthen.com/ is a free service which helps you with this.

Email, for example, 3days@followupthen.com to get a response in 3 days.  There are many other [time formats available](http://www.followupthen.com/how#timeformats).  After the specified time period, the service will reply to the email.  For your use case, you'll likely want to BCC the followup address.

Answer (score -3):

If you're using Google Apps for Domains their might be a CRM type application that provided this functionality.