# Search in Gmail - How to search the mails without reply?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I'd like to do a search in my Gmail to find out the mails that I sent without reply.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
label:sent -has:reply
```

it seems that the 'has' operator only accept :attachment

Is there a way to search the un-replied mails?

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8671/manage-un-replied-gmail-conversations

Answer (score 17):

I don't know of a direct way to do this, but you can create a filter that marks any mail containing "`Re:`" with a specific label (lets say `RE`), and the search for `-{label:RE}`

alternatively, skip the labeling part and search for `-{"re:"}`

Comment: Thanks Ophir, but if people use web gmail to reply a mail, the subject won't contain the `RE` or something like this.

Comment: @Johnny Just tested it - it does ad a 'Re' - click the 'show details' link and it will show you the mail header.

Comment: @Ophir I see, yes the subject has the 'Re'. There is another problem, the gmail server seems to ignore the ':', which means, when I search for "Re:", it will show mails that contains "re". That would be a lot of non-reply mails.

Comment: use quotes. and you can skip the tagging - just search `-{"re:"}`

Comment: @Ophir @Johnny I think the correct one will be `-subject:"re:"` to search only in the subjects of the e-mails. It still ignores the colon, so you might endup filtering out something that you don't want to.

Comment: @Ophir I tried the `-{"re:"}` search, it stil show me some reply mails. I checked those mail subjects, they did contain the "Re: " string. It's wired that why this hasn't been filtered out?

Comment: @Lipis yes, I agree that it shoult be `-subject:"re:"`, but the current problem is not that it filters more that expected. Even when I use `-{"re:"}`, it turns out that some reply mail still shows in the result

Comment: @Johnny check their title and if there is no `"re"` string (as a whole word) included then there is nothing wrong with the results, but with the query.

Comment: @Lipis the strange thing is that they did have "Re:" in the subject.

Comment: @Lipis - I can confirm that mail with the subject, for example, "Re: Debugging" shows up when I search for `-subject:"re:"`.  And no, it's not case-sensitive.

Comment: The thing causing the problem is searching rather than filtering I think - I came to this answer (and upvoted) following a bit of a google search, and the filtering insight was the thing I needed to make my solution work - I've posted mine as a seperate answer - but it probably would need merging with this - not sure if that's an applicable thing... would appricate advice...

Comment: This answer does not address the case where the un-replied-to email is already itself a reply to something.  E.g. someone e-mails me "A", and I reply ("Re: A") but never hear back again.  How do I find this "Re: A" e-mail that I sent?

Comment: -{"re:"} Doesn't work for me either. Threading is off. It seems to hide any email that ever had a reply, which includes the initially sent mail. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I don't think this solution works anymore.  it shows many conversations that had replies in conversation view.

Comment: you could also add from:me to the search. helped for me.

Answer (score 15):

I wanted to move all the mails I had sent to people and had not received a reply, into a label in Gmail. After trying different queries for an hour, I realised multiple queries would do the trick. And this worked for me.

1.
Search for

> in:inbox to:me category:personal

Select all conversations that match this search, and **Label as:** Create new Label → **Replied**

2.
Search for

> in:inbox from:me -label:replied

Select all conversations that match this search, and **Label as:** Create new Label → **NoReplyPlusChats**

3.
Search for

> label:NoReplyPlusChats is:chats

Select all conversations that match this search, and Remove Label **NoReplyPlusChats** → Apply

4.
Rename Label **NoReplyPlusChats** to **NoReply**

5.
Delete Label **Replied**

Now all your un-replied mails have the label: **NoReply**

(**NOTE:** Label **NoReply** would still contain your synced notes from smartphones, Apple Notes etc.)

Comment: Actually, in the first step, you can skip the "in:inbox" bit, this was specific to my situation. I moved all my sent mail to inbox, so this is the only way I could send all threads without replies back to Sent Mail Folder.

Comment: This doesn't work. I followed your steps and I still don't get my non replied emails.

Answer (score 8):

I decided to use this search operator:

```
from:me -subject:"re:" -is:chats -is:draft -has:userlabels
```

It's not perfect, but it cuts down on a lot of the conversations.

Answer (score 5):

Just a few years late, but I wrote a Gmail plugin to help with this. It's been pretty popular so far and is probably used by thousands of people by now. You can find instructions for it here:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20131231004200/http://jonathan-kim.com:80/2013/gmail-no-response/
- https://github.com/hijonathan/google-scripts/blob/master/gmail-no-response.js

It does a more sophisticated look up of who hasn't replied to your email, and you can tweak it to be even more effective to your use case.

Comment: I don't know anything about Google scripting, but I think a script needs to start with a `myFunction` entry point.  I wanted to run the script once to see whether it worked...

Answer (score 2):

None of the previous answers worked for me. Searching for `-subject:re` and equivalents seem to match EVERY conversation. I believe this is because that search is positive for the first message in the conversation (which does not have "Re:" in the subject line).

What works for me is:

1. Create a label (I called it "HasReply") using the filter: `subject:(+re)`
2. Then search for `-label:hasreply` or `-label:hasreply -from:me`

The logic here is that the first search will find all of the conversations with a reply. The second will then exclude those - leaving the messages without replies.

Adding the `-from:me` addresses a corner case where I'm searching a bunch of emails, sent NOT from me, to multiple recipients, and I want to find the ones NOBODY has replied to. Without the `-from:me` the results will for some reason include conversations where I am the only person who has replied. Adding this would not be appropriate in answering the original question, where the person wanted to find emails he had sent (which this would exclude) and had not received a reply to.

Alas, it is still not perfect. I create and apply the filter ("to matching conversations") and all is good. Then new replies come in and they don't seem to be added to the label...so I have to go back in like I'm editing the filter and re-apply it to catch the latest messages.

Comment: Why do we need the plus sign in (+re)? I read the documentation, but couldn't figure out what it means. Thanks.

Comment: not really working well enough for me

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ophir’s answer (I'm not sure if it’s possible to merge answers—I'm sure someone will pop along if neccessarily).

Filter for `-subject:"re:"` as mentioned—I labeled all such messages reply. (Has to be a filter because you want to label the thread not the reply.)

The search string I then had to use was:

```
-label:reply (from:myEmail OR from:myOtherEmail) -(variousKeyWordsThatSpecifySelfMails OR ect) -(to:myEmail OR to:myEmail)
```

Also—I'm afraid I'm not *quite* answering the OP—this will find all *single* emails that didn't get a reply. If someone emailed me, and I emailed back, and then there was no reply—that won't be found...