# Gmail no-reply reminder

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Manage un-replied GMail conversations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8671/manage-un-replied-gmail-conversations)

Is there a way to get a notice if I send an email to someone expecting a reply, but after a few days they haven't replied to it?

Either something already in gmail, or  an extension would also work.

For example if I send a friend a message like "hey I'm coming to New York next weekend, where should we meet" I would like to be notified if they didn't reply to it so I can remember to try to reach them through other means.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Boomerang](http://www.boomeranggmail.com/) for gmail. It has add-on and extensions for both chrome and firefox

Comment: +1 Boomerang looks cool. I like the way it offers to return a message to the inbox 1 day before a date it finds

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is no. Gmail is an email client not a diary tool.

I personally achieve the above by having a label called "waiting" that I check every day!

Another solution, could be a reminder on Google calendar, that would drop an email into your inbox too.