# List Gmail conversations where last reply is not from me

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

I need to list all the Email threads where the last reply is not from me.

This is to make sure that there are no mail threads where I have not replied to the client.

What filters should I add in addition to this.

```
to:me -is:chats -is:draft  category:primary
```

Comment: I doubt you can achieve this with a filter. What I usually do, is to mark the message _unread_ if I don't want to reply to it right away. In Gmail, you click the down arrow on the right side of the message, and select _Mark unread from here_. Optionally, also star it (or add a label). This lets me keep track of threads I need to act on.

Comment: This is the opposite of the problem described here: [Manage un-replied GMail conversations](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/8671/354) Perhaps some of the suggestions there could also work for you.

Answer (score 2):

In Gmail "Email threads" are named "conversations".

Gmail search doesn't have operators to find conversations where last reply meet certain criteria.  You could use filters, but they should set before receiving that replies.

Instead, implement a email management workflow. The simplest principle is to archive all the conversations that doesn't require a reply from you, so in your Inbox you will have only conversations that require a reply from you. Actually [Inbox by Gmail](http://www.google.com/inbox/) was designed to help implement this principle.

Consider to research about ["zero inbox" Gmail](http://google.com/search?q="zero%20inbox") and ["Get Things Done" Gmail](https://www.google.com/search?q="Get%20Things%20Done"%20Gmail).

By the way there is a script to move a way for a certain time those conversations that you can't or don't want to reply immediately. To learn about this go to [Gmail Snooze with Google Apps Script](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/gmail-snooze-with-apps-script.html).

**References**
[Conversations - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900?hl=en)
[Search in Gmail - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6593?hl=en)
[An inbox that works for you - Official Gmail Blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2014/10/an-inbox-that-works-for-you.html)